# Map not showing up when set to GDA2020

Tags: coordinate-system, epsg, australia, gda2020

When I open the quickmapservices/OSM (or Google) map it opens up on a EPSG:4326 (default), but since I am in Australia I need to use the GDA2020 projection. When I try to change the CRS to GDA2020, the map disappears and shows that its loading but nothing happens. The map never shows up so it doesn't allow me to use the required projection.

What could be the issue?

Comment: `EPSG` on it's own is meaningless.  Which EPSG code did you select? there are several ~ https://epsg.org/search/by-name/?query=GDA2020&

Comment: While it's possible to do datum shift in map services, it is very comptutationally expensive to do so, and not at all best practice. If you need/want a GDA2020 service I suggest you find a native one or create your own.